# Bug in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

[image: Screenshot of XXXX]

I am currently on 91 points, and I have got the *Edit Community Wiki* privilege! Why?

Comment: Odds are you had 100 rep at some point, but someone unupvoted some of your content, unaccepted an answer, you downvoted a few posts, etc. and pushed you back below 100 rep.

Comment: When I view your privileges you don't have it.

Comment: Exactly, would it be possible to parse logs to check? 
I cant see anything in my votes section! Should it display there even?

Comment: @neoeahit are you sure you are editing a CW post and not making a suggested edit?  If you have <100 rep, you can still edit them, but they will go into the Suggested Edit review queue for approval,

Comment: Well I got "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – edit community wiki learn more" as a notification!

Comment: Then it is what Servy said.  And if someone upvoted you then immediately unupvoted you, it wouldn't be recorded in your rep history, but would have triggered the privilege

Comment: But that should reflect in my votes section on my profile. Nehow, my point was just to bring this to the attention to the developers of stackoverflow. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @neoeahit When a user upvotes and unupvotes you on the same day, the events get collapsed and hidden from view so as not to flood your reputation history with useless events. An unupvote event is only ever shown if it occurs on a different day than the original upvote.